# How can I play a sound that will be in the application folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, soundplayer

I am trying to make that when the program initialize it plays a sound, but when I pass the installer to someone else it doesn't work since the destination is not correct in their computer.

How can I refer to the file in a way that will work in others computer?

Here is the code that I used:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private SoundPlayer unacabeza = new SoundPlayer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        unacabeza.SoundLocation = @"c:\Por_una_Cabeza_-_Carlos_Gardel_Gcxv7i02lXc.wav";
        unacabeza.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: When installating, create a folder in C:\ProgramData\YouApplicationName for example and put your wav file in it.

Comment: use a relativve path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put the **wav** file in the **Resources** Folder 
when you do that you don't have to worry about the location or file delete by user ,you can done that by

**solution Explore > Properties > double click on Resources** 
then  a new tab will open, drag and drop your **wav** file into it

***and rebuild the project***

to **play the wav** file from the **resources** all you need is

```
SoundPlayer test= new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.'filename');
test.play();
```

**or**
if you just need to play the **wav** from the app folder you can

- `SoundPlayer test = new SoundPlayer(Application.StartupPath + "\\filename.wav");`
- `SoundPlayer test = new SoundPlayer(".\\filename.wav");`

Answer (score 0):

You can place the wav file in the execution folder, then replace your code with just `unacabeza.SoundLocation = @"Por_una_Cabeza_-_Carlos_Gardel_Gcxv7i02lXc.wav";`